# Minecraft Player On World Join event

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Im newbie to Java, how can i handle current player joined the world?

```java
package page.a0x77.kubecraft;

import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraftforge.client.ClientCommandHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.event.RegistryEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.event.entity.EntityJoinWorldEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.event.entity.player.*;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPostInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.PlayerEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;

@Mod(
        modid = Kubecraft.MOD_ID,
        name = Kubecraft.MOD_NAME,
        version = Kubecraft.VERSION
)
public class Kubecraft {

    @SubscribeEvent
    public void playerLoggedInEvent(EntityJoinWorldEvent event) {
//        ClientCommandHandler.instance.executeCommand(Minecraft.getMinecraft().player, "your command");
            System.out.println("TEST");
    }

}
```

I want to make auto auth on player joined, send message to chat on join.

Comment: And whats the issue? Is it not printing?

Comment: @alexholstv Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
@EventBusSubscriber
public static class Class {
  @SubscribeEvent
  public static void onEvent(EntityJoinWorldEvent event) {
      if ((event.getEntity() instanceof PlayerEntity)) {
        LogManager.getLogger().info("Joined!");
      }
  }
}
```

I thought maybe you'd need the instance of the player to be able to get it to work.

Comment: You should also get used to using `LogManager.getLogger()`.

Comment: did you put it inside a `@EventBusSubscriber` class?

Comment: I updated my answer to show the `@EventBusSubscriber` class. If this still doesn't work, please link a pastebin of your file. You must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```java
...

@Mod(
        modid = Kubecraft.MOD_ID,
        name = Kubecraft.MOD_NAME,
        version = Kubecraft.VERSION
)
public class Kubecraft {

 ...

        @SubscribeEvent
        public static void onEvent(EntityJoinWorldEvent event) {
            Timer timer = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                    if(!sent) Minecraft.getMinecraft().player.sendChatMessage("/setblock ~ ~ ~ grass");
                    sent = true;
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(false); // Only execute once
            if(!sent) {
                timer.start();
            }
        }
    }
...
```