# Log the name of the player that joins the mc server

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

Im new to java and minecraft mods but i want to set up a server side mod where whenever someone joins the world it would trigger a webhook and send a msg to the discord.

I am using MCreator and i just want to log the name of the person that joined

here is my current code:

```
package net.mcreator.discord.procedures;

import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.Event;
import net.minecraftforge.event.entity.player.PlayerEvent;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

@Mod.EventBusSubscriber
public class LoginTrackerProcedure {
    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void onPlayerLoggedIn(PlayerEvent.PlayerLoggedInEvent event) {
      System.out.println("test");
          System.out.println(event.getPlayer().getDisplayName().getString());
          System.out.println("test");
          execute(event);
    }

    public static void execute() {
        execute(null);
    }

    private static void execute(@Nullable Event event) {
    }
}
```

a lot of boiler plate was made through MCreator i just want this line to work `System.out.println(event.getPlayer().getDisplayName().getString());`

this is the error screen
[image: error]

i have looked into these docs: https://nekoyue.github.io/ForgeJavaDocs-NG/javadoc/1.16.5/net/minecraftforge/event/entity/player/PlayerEvent.PlayerLoggedInEvent.html

and it looks like the getPlayer is a method

Comment: I know nothing about Minecraft development, but I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61642864/11434552) that looks like another way to detect when a player logs in using `EntityJoinWorldEvent`, might be worth a shot if you can't get `PlayerLoggedInEvent` working

Comment: Have you considered using a variant of a bukkit/spigot mc server with forge? That would grant you access to the bukkit api, `PlayerJoinEvent`, and more.